# Unique representations of positive integers?

Tags: number-theory

I was thinking about unique representations of the positive integers by a subset of the positive integers.

For the representation every element of the subset of positive integers may be used AT MOST ONCE.

So we consider unique representations of the positive integers by some operator and some subset of the positive integers where every element of the subset may be used at most once.

For the (operator) sum this subset is the powers of 2.
For the (operator) product this subset is the primes and the prime powers.

These are the only 2 solutions I know about.

What OTHER unique representations exist for the positive integers ?

To avoid confusion and mistakes ;

1) I know every positive integer is the sum of 4 squares 
THAT IS NOT UNIQUE HOWEVER AND THUS NO (NEW) VALID ANSWER.

2) Making a bijection from a subset of the integers to the primes , prime powers or powers of 2 is ALSO NO (NEW) VALID ANSWER.

3) EVERY operator (of the answer) between any elements of the set should be a positive integer !

Im not sure there are such other unique representations , but I cannot (dis)prove that either.

My apologies for the late edit , I do not have alot of time.

Maybe this is better as a comment but Im confused why the tag " representation " has been removed.

edit :

the factorial number system shows how other unique representations can be given for the sum operator.

So this reduces the question for operators that are not the simple sum.

Comment: first of all, you need to clarify what you mean by a "representation".

Comment: Also:  "operator" ($+$, $\times$, and then?) and unique ($21=(1+4)+16=4+(16+1)$)

Comment: Well by represention I mean by a subset of the positive integers and some operator.

Comment: @mick: And why is "sum of different powers of 2" not a valid answer (in shouty caps, even)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I do not know what comes next. Thats part of the answer I guess ?

Comment: @HenningMakholm it IS VALID , but I ask for OTHER solutions.

Comment: @mick: Your point (2) shouts loud and clear that it is "ALSO NO VALID ANSWER". If that is not what you meant, you might want to edit the question.

Comment: positive integers are NOT all UNIQUE products of a set of prime powers (which includes primes, but I'll exclude $1$ to avoid too trivial cases). For instance $8=2\times4$ (both sides contain a set of prime powers).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system

Comment: The representation as a sum of powers of $2$ is not unique. For instance $8 = 2^3 = 2^2 + 2^2 = 2^1 + 2^1 +  2^1 + 2^1 + 2^1 + 2^1 + 2^1 + 2^1$. So you should make your question more precise.

Comment: I edited. Thanks for the comments. I think the OP is clear now.

Comment: so the factorial number system doesn't answer your question then?

Comment: @barakmanos yes for the sum operator this works !
see the edit.
Thank you. +1

Comment: Btw I wonder does using the factorial number system have advantages in number theory ? Does the factorial number system occur in proofs ?

Comment: You can also use the Fibonacci base system: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibrep.html

Comment: @barakmanos Doesn't that require the "no two consecutive" restriction in order to have uniqueness?  I also don't see how factorial base gives uniqueness without the restriction of "no two digits of the same place value", in which case any old base will work.

Comment: @mick The primes and prime powers don't work for $\cdot$ in the same sense as the powers of two for $+$.  You can write $27$ as the product of $\{3, 9\}$ as well as just $\{27\}$.  Could you please clarify this in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rephrase your question as follows: **What are the $\mathbb F_2$ vector space structures on the natural numbers?**

A *unique representation via a fixed subset and an operation* is nothing else then the unique expression using a basis. In order to answer the question: Proof that every infinite set K has the same cardinality as the set of its finite subsets. The latter clearly has a $\mathbb F_2$ vector space structure by the symmetric difference.